# Synonyms OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, opensearch

Can I add a synonyms file to an existing OpenSearch Index or will I have to create a new Index and Put all my documents in new Index. If second option then how to Transfer all Documents from one Index to a new Index?

I tried to create a new test Index an put the Synonyms file and it worked but now I want to to add it to my main Index that contains 70K documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).
Set wait_for_completion to false (Running reindex asynchronously)  and get the task id. Use task_id in Task API to follow status of reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "markazproducts"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "markazproductsv2"
  }
  
}
```

Worked in AWS OpenSearch althogh request timed out